# compile prolog code+C code into binary using swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I just have a question which I can't find a accurate answer online ..

Using [`swipl-ld`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compilation)
can help to combine Prolog and C code together, and eventually generating one signal 
executable binary.

But there is one thing I am confused with...

In the generated binary, does the `Prolog Interpreter` (Virtual Machine or others) still exist?

If so, then probably the original `Prolog` code is stored as `string` in the `.rodata` section of ELF binary, but after a searching inside this section, I didn't find the code.. But perhaps the original code has been transformed into `bytecode`, and that's why I just can't find it at all..

If not, then how can Prolog code directly translate into semantic equivalent asm code based on SWI-Prolog?  I have read some materials about the implementation of GNU-Prolog, based on WAM virtual machine, however, I haven't found any materials about the implementation of  SWI-Prolog...

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiled binary does not contain your original source code nor the whole Prolog interpreter. However it does contain your program in form of bytecode compiled by the [`qsave_program/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=runtime) predicate. This bytecode is executed by Prolog *emulator*, which is a subset of the Prolog interpreter used during a normal interactive dialog, and which is also included in the compiled binary.

All relevant information can be found in the [Generating Runtime Applications](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=runtime) section of the SWI-Prolog documentation.

Comment: Hello liori, Thank you for your answer! then, is there any way that using SWI-Prolog to directly generate asm code from Prolog code..? I think GNU-Prolog can do this job...

Comment: I mean asm code with same semantic and execution model, but doesn't need interpreter/emulator to interpret it..

Comment: @computereasy: no idea, i'm not actually sure it's possible due to all the ways you can construct code in Prolog at runtime. However, it could be a perfect follow-up question here on the site.

Comment: I think GNU-Prolog has a solution based on their previous work [wamcc: Compiling Prolog to C](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=19884FDC92375E25388B872B4587C998?doi=10.1.1.45.1122&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but it seems that `SWI-Prolog` just choose a more natural way to implement. Anyway, thx:)